# Malayalam font not working properly; letters don't combine

Tags: fonts, language-support, malayalam

Unicode Malayalam fonts are not working properly after the version 10.04 LTS. Characters that should combine do not join each other.

Examples: വ്റ, ശ്രീ, ഗ്ര

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS now

Comment: did you try the usual 'podapatti' installation? :P

Comment: @pomsky I think he means that it did work on 10.04, but using 14.04 it's not working anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Install the package `ttf-malayalam-fonts` (`fonts-mlym` on 16.04+), if you haven't already done so. Then create the file `~/.config/fontconfig/conf.d/10-prefer-malayalam.conf` with the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
        <alias>
                <family>serif</family>
                <prefer>
                        <family>Lohit Malayalam</family>
                </prefer>
        </alias>
        <alias>
                <family>sans-serif</family>
                <prefer>
                        <family>Lohit Malayalam</family>
                </prefer>
        </alias>
        <alias>
                <family>monospace</family>
                <prefer>
                        <family>Lohit Malayalam</family>
                </prefer>
        </alias>
</fontconfig>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (Install Malayalam fonts in Ubuntu):

```
sudo apt-get install fonts-smc fonts-samyak-mlym fonts-mlym fonts-lohit-mlym
```

or check these pages out:
https://smc.org.in/fonts/

https://www.google.com/get/noto/#sans-mlym

https://launchpad.net/~smcproject/+archive/ubuntu/repo

Comment: This is not working.... " Unable to locate package fonts-mlym" ...comment is received.

Comment: ahh shame! I will look at few repos and pull and test them locally later in the evening for you.